# Pandas dataframe read csv gives hidden characters underlied in the value

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I try to read an CSV provided by this [link](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Ecziegler/BX/BX-CSV-Dump.zip) which usually used to build reccomendation system. I used BX-Books.csv and BX-Book-Ratings.csv. This is the example of BX-Books.csv

```
"ISBN";"Book-Title";"Book-Author";"Year-Of-Publication";"Publisher";"Image-URL-S";"Image-URL-M";"Image-URL-L"
"0195153448";"Classical Mythology";"Mark P. O. Morford";"2002";"Oxford University Press";"http://images.amazon.com/images/P/0195153448.01.THUMBZZZ.jpg";"http://images.amazon.com/images/P/0195153448.01.MZZZZZZZ.jpg";"http://images.amazon.com/images/P/0195153448.01.LZZZZZZZ.jpg"
"0002005018";"Clara Callan";"Richard Bruce Wright";"2001";"HarperFlamingo Canada";"http://images.amazon.com/images/P/0002005018.01.THUMBZZZ.jpg";"http://images.amazon.com/images/P/0002005018.01.MZZZZZZZ.jpg";"http://images.amazon.com/images/P/0002005018.01.LZZZZZZZ.jpg"
```

And the BX-Book-Ratings.csv

```
"User-ID";"ISBN";"Book-Rating"
"276725";"034545104X";"0"
"276726";"0155061224";"5"
"276727";"0446520802";"0"
```

I try to read both of the file with this code:

```
Books = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Yosafat VS\PycharmProjects\Recomendation_KNN\Data\BX-Books.csv", sep=';', error_bad_lines=False, encoding="latin-1")
Ratings = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Yosafat VS\PycharmProjects\Recomendation_KNN\Data\BX-Book-Ratings.csv", sep=';', error_bad_lines=False, encoding="latin-1")
```

When i try to check the data, i found some ISBN on both csv are loaded wrongly (it should be not a ISBN code) like this

```
        count
ISBN
_____________   
0330299891  2
0375404120  2
0586045007  1
9022906116  2
9032803328  1
...     ...
cn113107    1
ooo7156103  1
§423350229  1
´3499128624     1
Ô½crosoft   1
```

But when i check the CSV i cannot found any problems with the data, and ISBN seems right. However, each value in both csv are enclosed with double quotes and BX-Book.csv usinG ANSI instead UTF-8. BX-Book-Rating using UTF-8

That's why when i try to map pivoted BX-Book-Ratings into BX-Books, it gives me error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index([' 0330299891', ' 0375404120', ' 9022906116', '*0452281903',\n       '+0451197399', '0 7336 1053 6', '0 907 062 008', '0*708880258',\n       '00000000', '000000000',\n       ...\n       'O77O428452', 'O786001690', 'O805063196', 'O9088446X', 'O971880107',\n       'SBN425037452', 'X000000000', 'XXXXXXXXXX', 'ZR903CX0003',\n       '`3502103682'],\n      dtype='object', name='ISBN', length=135794)] are in the [index]"
```

Which actually the key are exists in both csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes we will find some puzzle encoding problem, and most of the time we can ignore it because these lines are few.

we can use `open` to handle the job.

```py
file = 'BX-Books.csv'
with open(file, errors='ignore') as fr:
    data = fr.read()
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=';', error_bad_lines=False)
```

result:

```
# BX-Book-Ratings.csv  (1149780, 3) -> filelines 1149781
# BX-Books.csv         (271360, 8)  -> filelines 271380
```

cols:

```
# BX-Book-Ratings.csv
['User-ID', 'ISBN', 'Book-Rating']
    
# BX-Books.csv 
['ISBN', 'Book-Title', 'Book-Author', 'Year-Of-Publication', 'Publisher',
  'Image-URL-S', 'Image-URL-M', 'Image-URL-L']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this particular example:

```py
file = 'BX-Books.csv'
with open(file, errors='ignore') as fr:
    data = fr.read()    

data_list = data.strip().split('\n')   
obj = pd.Series(data_list)
obj = obj.str.strip('"')
dfn = obj.str.split('";"', expand=True)
dfn.columns = dfn.iloc[0]
dfn.drop(0, inplace =True)
```

dfn shape:

```
# BX-Books.csv         (271379, 8)  -> filelines 271380(with a header row)
```